# Is it possible to specify multiple ID for model in Kendo Web UI?

Tags: model, kendo-ui, identifier

I am completely new to Kendo UI, so maybe I missing something, but after reading the docs API: http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/model it seems Kendo is limited only to work with single ID.

For example, let's say I have a grid in which each row is identified by pair of values (because underlying data have such constraint). So, if I've read it right there is no straightforward way to express this in Kendo?

One workaround I can think of is creating some ad-hoc value which is encoded ids like "value1|value2" (string) and when getting data back from UI, decoding them back.

Is there any more clear way?

**Specific example**

To focus on something substantial:

http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/editing-inline.html

and the relevant code is (from .cshtml file):

`.Model(model => model.Id(p => p.ProductID))`

in my case it would be (the simplest way I can think of):

`.Model(model => model.Id(p => p.ProductComboId1Id2))`

where `ProductComboId1Id2` is a string encoded as described above.

### Solution (sort of)

See at the bottom of the page, it was a problem with Kendo installation. Installer script didn't install one crucial .js file and entire framework went weird. My problem was one of those misbehaviours.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use multiple IDs on a single grid.  Below I've included syntax for declaring them as well as how to access them via javascript.

**Declaration**

```
        .Model(model =>
        {
            model.Id(i => i.ProductID);
            model.Id(i => i.ProductID2);
        })
```

**Accessing**

```
function GetIDs() {
var itemGrid = $("#GRIDNAME").data("kendoGrid");
var dataItem = itemGrid.dataItem($(this));
var ID1 = dataItem.ProductID;
var ID2 = dataItem.ProductID2;}
```

function GetID() would be invoked on the grid like this through the row's command column:

```
        columns.Command(command =>
        {
            command.Custom("Edit").Text("Edit").Click("GetIDs");
            command.Destroy();
        });
```

Comment: Thank you. What setup do you use? In my case it is ASP.Net MVC3 + KendoUIWeb 2012.2.710 and all I got is the last specified id, I mean for the code as you shown I will get url with `?ProductID2=something` and of course when I check `Product1` for passed object in the method I will get default value for it (0 in case of ints and alike).

Comment: Found it. Problem was not in code, but in buggy (IMHO) installation.

Comment: Glad you got it.  I'm sorry I wasn't prompt in getting a reply to your comment.  Happy hunting!

Comment: This doesn't work. The generated schema.model.id would be only `ProductID2`

Comment: A Telerik tech stated in one of the forums that, "The Kendo datasource does not support composite data keys".
https://www.telerik.com/forums/composite-datakey-in-kendo-ui-mvc#JlhcEtSyAEqMWaW6TjnDKQ

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a bug in install script, or not, I don't know, however the problem was Kendo installer didn't install one crucial file. Namely...

When you install Kendo package via NuGet `Install-Package KendoIOWeb` it will **NOT** install a file `kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js` and this one is a crucial one. With it all of the suddent I get confirmation for delete, id`s are sent via POST instead of GET (exactly how I configured them), the page is shown after action, in short -- finally it makes sense.

So to fix it, don't mess with code, just download manually zip file from Kendo website, get this file and put it in Content directory.

Since NuGet installer for Kendo created such structure `Content\kendo\2012.2.710` and below are all the files I put this extra .js file in `Content\kendo` this way it will remind me it was manual addition.